# No gui after upgraded to ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, boot

i've upgraded  to ubuntu 10.04  , after reboot it is displaying command prompt,gui is not displaying

sudo update-grub

sudo apt-get install build-essential

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Have you tried to login via tty? What was the result of above commands?

Comment: First type **sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade**, re-boot, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

On the command prompt, type `startx` to see if the gui is displaying again.